# q-checkbox custom validation

Tags: typescript, vue.js, validation, quasar-framework

like the title implies I've got a problem with custom validation on my q-checkbox, which can't get validation over the normal quasar way.

Here my checkboxes with custom DIVs for my Errorbox

```
 <q-item style="padding-left: 0; padding-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0">
                      <q-checkbox
                          id="acceptedPrice"
                          v-model="acceptedPrice"
                          label='Ich habe die Kategorie "Preise / Teilnahmebedingungen"
                    gelesen und stimme ihnen zu.'
                          style="padding-bottom: 0;"
                      />
                    </q-item>
                    <div v-if="showError"
                         style="padding: 8px 0 2px 16px; line-height: 1; min-height: 0;
                           color: #C10015; font-size: 13px;">
                      Bitte Pflichtfeld anhaken
                    </div>
                    <q-item style="padding-left: 0; padding-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0">
                      <q-checkbox
                          id="acceptedAgreement"
                          v-model="acceptedAgreement"
                          label='Ich habe die Kategorie "Einwilligung" gelesen und
                     stimme der Nutzung meiner Daten zu.'
                          style="padding-bottom: 0;"
                      />
                    </q-item>
```

My ts:

```
const acceptedPrice = ref<boolean>(false);
const acceptedAgreement = ref<boolean>(false);
const showError = ref<boolean>(false);

async function onsubmit() {
  if (acceptedPrice.value !== true && acceptedAgreement.value !== true) {
    showError.value = true;
  }
  if (acceptedPrice.value === true && acceptedAgreement.value === true) {
    const success = await buildingBoomForm.value?.validate();
    if (success === true) {
      Notify.create({
        color: 'positive',
        icon: 'cloud_done',
        message: 'Formular erfolgreich versendet!'
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Now the message get displayed when the user forgets to tck the boxes, but isn't reactive like I wanted it to do it. When it is displayed, it shouldn't get displayed after they tick the box.

I've tried it with a computed but didn't quite got it to work. Watchers I consider but I really don't think its a usecase for it.